# Filter participants list based on availability

Tags: excel-365

For a company internal training, people can choose between 4 possible dates.
They can select any number of the dates. Some select 1, some select multiple, some select all.
Now I want to plan the training, taking in account the prefered date of participation of each trainee.

The maximum of participants per date is 10 people and they only have to participate 1x.

e.g.: if person A has only selected day 2, then they have to get priority for a spot in that training session.

Since the number of participants is rather high, it's very difficult to select the best day for each one manually.

I have created a Table in Excel with the following layout:

column 1 = name participant

column 2 = availability for day 1

column 3 = availability for day 2

column 4 = availability for day 3

column 5 = availability for day 4

I've tried Filter formula; I tried sorting, using randomize, using substition codes
None of them yield the desired result.

any idea to solve this is welcome :D

Answer (score 0):

I am new on answering questions here on StackOverflow so please if this doesn't match the standard let me know and I will delete the post. I'm just trying to help.

Personally I think excel is not the tool for this but anyway let's try to build something useful.

I think you can use the following approach but you need to assume that you can have more than 10 persons for 1 date, this is something we can not controll without blocking cells interactivly.If you have a maximum of 10 people per session but 12 picks only the day 1, you will be tied.

So let suppouse we're trying to find the best distribuition with the given dates without controll if more than 10 people selects the same date.

For those that select only 1 date, we will need to assume that the selected day is the one to assign them.

For the rest that are selecting more than one date, allocate them using a probability function. I have used the following, but it can be modelated as needed, and also weighted or whatever:

Imagine that date 1 is selected by 8 persons, date 2 by 15 and day 3 by 12, then calculate, y1 = 1 - (d1 / (d1 + d2 + d3 + d4)) => 1 - (8 / (8 + 15 + 12 + 5)), for each date, (avoiding formal formulation). This is going to provide you a probability function that priorizes the allocation of the user in low voted dates. Then transform this probability in a range of numbers, so you can use it to decide with a random generated number where to allocate the user in case he have selected more than one day. So take y1 and multiply it with the sum of the selected days by date (d1 + d2 + d3 + d4) * y1. Now we have a proability function converted in a range of numbers that can be used to handle the allocation.

Pleas note that sometimes you will only need to decide over two dates, then you only need to use the accumulative range of numbers for this dates. This means if date1 have 32 values in the range, and date2 have 25 numbers in the range, then you need to generate a random number that provides you a number between 1 and (32 + 25) = 57, and just test if this number is less than 32 the the user is allocated in d1 if the number is greather than 32 then the user will be allocated in date2. The same if you're deciding between 3 dates, assuming d1 have a range of 32 numbers, d2 25 and d3 28, then you just need to generate a random number between 1 and ( 32 + 25 + 28) and evaluate if this number is less than 32, 57 or 85.

When I say range i mean sum(d1 + d2 + d3 +d4) * (1- (d_n / (d1 + d2 +d3 +d4))), this will provide you the representation of the probability in a range of numbers. Where d1, d2, d3, d4 are the number of times that the users have selected this date.

To transform this into something usable in excel, the way I build it is using 3 tables (See the attached picture). The first table is the "survey" where people have selected the dates.

The second table is the one which contains the logic of the processing, this takes the probabilities calculated and converted to a range of numbers, and then generates a random number uniformly distributed to allocate the person, using a conditional formula that evaluates if the random number is less than the range of numbers for the given columns.

Finally the third table only maps the allocation to have an overview.

[Excel with the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogMJu.png)

Hope it helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).